# FilePond | onprocessfiles callback is not working if I uploaded files both the file type is supported and is not supported

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filepond

I tried to duplicate this issue but I couldn’t since it needs to set some server side codes and couldn’t do it on codesandbox.

But you can at least see working code on [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-filepond-live-demo-forked-ftoqcd?file=/src/index.js).

And this is [a record gif](https://gyazo.com/66da734e03f92676ee0f400bf1808cbf) for my problem.

So, when I upload multiple files and if one of the file types is not supported, user won’t be able to click the save button, but if user removes the file that is not supported and has only files that are supported, user should be able to click the save button.

But the issue I have is user can’t click the save button even though he has only files that are supported.

I disabled and abled the save button based with `imagesUploading` value that changes value depending on the file uploading status like start uploading, uploading right now or uploaded successfully.

```
function App() {
  const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);
  const [imagesUploading, setImagesUploading] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <FilePond
        files={files.map((file) => file.file)}
        maxFiles={50}
        server={{
          process: {
            ...
            },
            ondata: formData => {
            ...
            },
          },
        }}
        maxFileSize="10MB"
        acceptedFileTypes={["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png"]}
        allowMultiple={true}
        onupdatefiles={(fileItems) => {
          setFiles(fileItems);
        }}
        onaddfilestart={() => {
          console.log("onaddfilestart");
          setImagesUploading(true); // make the save button disabled
        }}
        onprocessfilestart={() => {
          console.log(`onprocessfilestart`);
          setImagesUploading(true); // make the save button disabled
        }}
        onprocessfiles={() => {
          console.log(`onprocessfiles`);
          setImagesUploading(false); // make the save button abled
        }}
        imageResizeTargetWidth={1920}
        allowImageTransform={true}
        imageTransformOutputQuality={70}
      />
      <button disabled={imagesUploading || files.length < 1}>Save</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

On the console, I see `onaddfilestart` and `imagesUploading: true` twice since there are two files are about to start uploading process.

Also, I see just `onprocessfilestart` letter and no value for `imagesUploading` and I assume because one of the file types is not supported, so process failed and the rest of callbacks(`onprocessfiles`) never got called where set `imagesUploading` value false to abled the button.

Does anybody have the same issue?

#### Attempts

There is a property named `dropValidation` that When files are enabled, files are validated before they are dropped. A file is not added when it's invalid.

I'm using this as a temporal solution right now.

Comment: processfile events are not fired when there is no `server` property because in that situation FilePond won't asynchronously upload the files, in that situation every dropped

Comment: There was no `server` above example because I just wanted to make it look simpler. I just added `server` to my example code as well